# Problem With Power Supply.?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, resistors, bridge-rectifier

I am using the following circuit to convert 230V AC into 12V and 3.3V DC.Here i am using a X rated capacitor instead of a transformer and i am taking 12V and 3.3V DC output from this circuit to power my loads.The circuit is build on a PCB and the PCB is properly covered in order to avoid direct electric contact to the mains through the circuit.Now the circuit is working fine.

But when i continuously power the circuit that is on and off the 230V AC input, some times the resistor R2(22ohm 1W) get damaged.I think the problem is due to the inrush current at the time of power on.

So please let me know that is this problem is due to inrush?
Is there any other reason for this?
If this is due to inrush what will be the suitable value for resistor to protect it from damage due to inrush?
How can i calculate the inrush current in this circuit?

[image]

Comment: That looks like a very dangerous design, no voltage isolation. If you're lucky you're gonna get zapped and killed till you die.

Comment: What is a 105j capacitor?

Comment: Try using the same resistor value with a higher wattage rating.

Comment: @karthikJay   Currently i am trying the same. i have placed a 2W resister instead of 1W and the circuit is under test. have any other solution..?

Comment: @Transistor 105j capacitor is an X rated capacitor and is used to step down AC like a transformer.

Comment: Yes, but what's its capacitance value in microfarads?

Comment: @Transistor it is a 1uF capacitor

Comment: The "12V load" output will only ever see 3.3 Volts. Please use a safe wall wart instead of this dangerous circuit - it is **not** isolated from the mains.

Comment: Resistors have voltage ratings.

Comment: Why did you decide to not use a transformer?

Comment: Please use the shift key on your keyboard to get capital letters and limit yourself to just one period per sentence. Also, what everyone else says, you will kill yourself with this contraption.

Comment: Thank you all for your great concern about the risk in this circuit. actually the circuit is completely build on PCB and the PCB is covered with a plastic box to avoid direct contact with the mains.

Comment: What's the value of C1?  It looks like "105"<something>.

Comment: @OlinLathrop the value of C1 is 1uF.

Answer (score 3):

To calculate inrush, assume everything is discharged and the AC line is connected at its peak.  You say your input is 230 VAC.  That's assumed to be a sine, so the peak is 325 V.

The elements limiting the inrush current are R2 and C1, which are in series.  Instantaneously, the 325 V is all applied across R2.  How fast that decays depends on C1.  Since the value for C1 is messed up in your schematic (all I see is "105"<something>) we can't help with that and you're on your own.

Even if the instantaneous energy dumped into R1 is low enough, the voltage may not be.  R1 must not only be rated for the short term energy handling (different from sustained power rating), but also the voltage.

A obvious thing to do would be to change R1 to a 2 W resistor, and of course make sure it's rated for 350 V at least, then see what happens.

In general when dealing with line power, you should derate significantly since the cost of failure can be quite high.

Comment: thank you for this valuable information . The value of capacitor is 1uF and i have updated the diagram.

Comment: @iqb: The capacitor is still mislabeled in the updated diagram.

Comment: Shouldn't you assume C1 is fully charged to the opposite polarity? Consider the situation where the power supply is unplugged at the negative peak of the sine wave, and reconnected at the positive peak. At 230VAC that leaves you with a worst-case 650V potential at connect.

Comment: @marc: C1 has a bleeder resistor across it.  It will be discharged to zero in reasonable cases.  Disconnecting for a short time would leave C2 charged, which reduces the apparent voltage.  You should at least look at this worst case scenario, but start with the normal case where C1 and C2 are discharged.

Comment: @iqb: No, "105j" is not a rating.  That may be what's printed on it.  "105" means 10 x 10^5 pF.  "j" is something specific to the manufacturer.  Neither of these belong on the schematic.

Comment: @OlinLathrop thanks for the information and i have removed it from the schematic

Comment: @OlinLathrop Ah, I forgot about the bleeder resistor. Fair enough :)

Answer (score 1):

The answers saying you almost certainly exceeded the resistor's voltage rating are correct. But it gets worse. The peak voltage of the power line isn't the highest level you might see. Transients in the single digit kilovolt range are common during electrical storms and when nearby loads are switched. You must use components that are designed and rated for across-the-line use.

I think the capacitor you're using is a CTM105VAJ. It's a mil-spec mylar capacitor. The "J" means 5% tolerance. It's intended for precision applications, like filters with sharp corners, rather than power circuits. Its voltage rating is 50 Vdc. You've been very lucky, if it's still undamaged. To find a suitable capacitor you should start by looking at motor start and run capacitors online. They'll give you a good idea of the size and price of what you need. You probably won't like what you see.

There's nothing inherently wrong with a circuit that is not isolated from the line. if the power supply *and* the load are enclosed, like electric tools, and for that matter, table lamps. You *can't* use your power supply like a wall wart though.

Carbon composition resistors are reputed to withstand brief voltage transients well above their rated voltage, but they're being discontinued by almost all manufacturers. The ASR series from Stackpole, carried by Digi-Key, would work.

Probably the least of your worries, but you can cut the component count quite a bit. The circuit following can replace everything to the left of your 3.3 V regulator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f83eQD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>